# Creating an input element with a dotted border

Tags: css, border

I want to place an input element in a form. However, instead of it having a solid-box border, I want it to have a dotted border.

This is similar to what basecamp has for inviting new people to existing projects. 
[image: Basecamp project access]

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: It is usually helpful to add some reference link, or a snapshot when you refer to something. For instance, I have no idea what basecamp is and how it invites people.

Comment: Drastically restyling form elements is really bad for usability.  Users have certain expectations when it comes to the general look and feel of form components.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the code I came up with:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="dotted">
```

**CSS**

```
#dotted {
    border:0;
    border-bottom: 2px dotted;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NZptx/1/).

Comment: I am unable to get the above style working. I am using twitter bootstrap, could that be overriding the styles you have provided above ?

Comment: It would be likely they would use this on multiple input fields, so a class would me more appropriate than an Id.

Comment: Yes may be there is some `CSS specificity` issue there. Do you find the above css overridden with existing css in Firebug or developer tools?

Answer (score 5):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="dotted-input">​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

CSS:

```
.dotted-input {
    border: 0px; 
    border-bottom:1px dotted #000;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<input type="text" style="border:0;border-bottom:2px dashed #c3c3c3;padding:5px;color:gray;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;">
```

If you want it not dashed, and just a solid line, replace "border-bottom:2px dashed #c3c3c3;" with "border-bottom:2px solid #c3c3c3;". And if you want it not 2px, and just 1px, replace "border-bottom:2px dashed #c3c3c3;" with "border-bottom:1px dashed #c3c3c3;". Also note the the part of the code that adds the 2px pixels of border on the bottom is "border-bottom:2px dashed #c3c3c3". The rest of the code I did is just for embellishment.

You could also refer to an stylesheet like this:

```
<style>
.classy{
border:0;
border-bottom:2px dashed #c3c3c3;
padding:5px;
color:gray;
font-family:Arial;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:14px;
}
</style>
```

And for the textbox you could do this:

```
<input type="text" class="classy">
```

Comment: Avoid using inline stylesheets

Answer (score 1):

Here's one

```
<input type="text" class="dotbox">​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

```
.dotbox{
    border:none;
    border-bottom:thin dashed black;
    padding-bottom:0;
    outline:none;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ksS65/)

Answer (score 0):

For the dotted border all around:

```
<input type="text" style="border:1px dotted #ccc">
```

for the dotted border at the side you want:

```
<input type="text" style="border-<side you want either top, bottom, left, right> 1px dotted #ccc>
```